# Comments box: expands into the div below

Tags: html, facebook, comments

I used the tool provided on the developers section at developers.facebook.com.  The comments box seems to work fine (other than I don't know how to moderate the comments), but the only thing is, that the posted comments expand down into the div below.  I'm sure this is something simple, and I'd expect the div to allow for this... can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the

```
<body>
```

tag in your app with this:

```
<body onLoad="FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(10);">
```

This will set the canvas to resize every 10ms (change the 10 value to edit this)